# Binding value when trying to bind price to view with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following is a simple pizza page menu with 5 pizza to select with a radio button. I have a function in my controller to display the selected pizza below the menu along with any special instructions inside a dive titled Order Summary. The problem is trying to display the price along with the chosen pizza.

AngularJS

```
pizzaApp.controller('pizzaCtrlr', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.model = {title: 'Our Menu'};

    $scope.changeMainDish = function(item) {
        $scope.model.mainDish = item;
        if (item === "Cheese Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 9.99; }
        if (item === "Pepperoni Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 10.99; }
        if (item === "Margherita Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 11.99; }
        if (item === "BBQ Chicken Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 12.99; }
        if (item === "Combo Pizza") { 
            console.log(item);
            $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 13.99; 
            console.log($scope.model.mainDish.price);
        }
    }

}]);
```

This is the portion of the html where I am trying to bind the price to the view. Everything displays except the price. When I try to console.log the price I get undefined.

```
    <div>
        <h3>Order Summary</h3>
        <pre>{{model.mainDish}} {{model.mainDish.price}} - {{model.specialInstructions}}</pre>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined because you are first assigning $scope.model.mainDish = item;
so in model,it  will look like this

```
{

  title:'Our Menu',
  mainDish:'itemNameHere' //it is stored as string
}
```

Now in if else chain you are setting model.mainDish.price="$99 something" here mainDish is a string so it wont work, in case mainDish is an object it will work.

Change your $scope.model to have mainDish an empty object first

```
$scope.model = {title: 'Our Menu',mainDish:{}};
```

and then set item to the model as

```
$scope.model.mainDish.name=item;
```

same goes to the price

```
$scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 12.99;
```

Order summary

```
<h3>Order Summary</h3>
{{model.mainDish.name}} {{model.mainDish.price}} - {{model.specialInstructions}}
</div>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.model = {title: 'Our Menu',mainDish:{}};
    $scope.change=function(){
    let item=$scope.item;
      $scope.model.mainDish.name=item;
        if (item === "Cheese Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 9.99; }
        if (item === "Pepperoni Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 10.99; }
        if (item === "Margherita Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 11.99; }
        if (item === "BBQ Chicken Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 12.99; }
        if (item === "Combo Pizza") { $scope.model.mainDish.price = '$' + 13.99;}
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="radio" ng-model="item" ng-click="change()" value="Cheese Pizza"/>Cheese Pizza<br>
<input type="radio" ng-model="item" ng-click="change()"  value="Pepperoni Pizza"/>Pepperoni Pizza<br>
<input type="radio" ng-model="item" ng-click="change()" value="Margherita Pizza"/>Margherita Pizza<br>
<input type="radio" ng-model="item" ng-click="change()" value="BBQ Chicken Pizza"/>BBQ Chicke Pizza<br>
<input type="radio" ng-model="item" ng-click="change()" value="Combo Pizza"/>Combo Pizza
 <h3>Order Summary</h3>
{{model.mainDish.name}} {{model.mainDish.price}} - {{model.specialInstructions}}
</div>
```